# Excel VBA - Coping activerow into different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make some code that will run through a list. Once it meets the criteria it will copy that row into a different shortsheet.

But for some reason i get a debug after it pastes the first line into the different sheet. The debug is on the paste function.

```
Sub UpdateSheetsPendingAction()

Sheets("Final_Data").Select

Dim Key As String
Dim SAANumber As String
Dim ReqSent As String
Dim AccOpen As String
Dim Rejected As String
Dim Opener As String
Dim SLADate As String
Dim InputDate As String
Dim PendingCompletion As String
Dim PendingAction As String
Dim Rejection As String
Dim ActRow As Range
Dim Import As Range

Dim CRow As String

For C = 1 To 10000 'Max Number of accounts
    CRow = C + 1
        Key = Range("A" + CRow).Value
        SAANumber = Range("B" + CRow).Value
        ReqSent = Range("E" + CRow).Value
        AccOpen = Range("F" + CRow).Value
        Rejected = Range("H" + CRow).Value
        Opener = Range("J" + CRow).Value
        SLADate = Range("M" + CRow).Value
        InputDate = Range("N" + CRow).Value
        PendingCompletion = Range("O" + CRow).Value
        PendingAction = Range("P" + CRow).Value
        Rejection = Range("Q" + CRow).Value
        'Requester = Range("R" + CRow).Value
        'AMREF = Range("S" + CRow).Value


        '''Pending Action
        If PendingAction <> "" Then
        Set ActRow = Range("A" + CRow + ":" + "AZ" + CRow)
        ActRow.Copy
            With Sheets(Opener).Select
            Range("A4").Select
            Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Insert
            Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Paste
            End With
        End If

Next C

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Paste`

To:

`Rows(ActiveCell.Row).PasteSpecial`

Add `Sheets("Final_Data").Select` after you call your `For` statement

Comment: This did indeed get rid of my error, but the code did not move to the next C ?

Comment: Please see revised answer. I've added `Sheets("Final_Data").Select` to the top of the loop. You're loop does not switch back to the `Final_Data` sheet. Oops I accidently edited your question with the change too! (If it's accepted you'll see it), otherwise follow my answer which i've updated too

Comment: Thank you very much! >_< goodness that was stupid of me... Appreciate the help.